# Writing string to a file in java

Tags: java

I have a file which contains sql statements.
Now in this file, I want to add a word "collate" after every 'char()' and 'varchar()' in the file.
How do you do that?

Comment: Find and replace will do. You can use notepad++ or any decent text editor

Comment: Please see the title properly...I need it in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the file line by line. On each String do two replaceAll( ... ) using your Strings above. Then write each line into a new File. When done, rename the original file to some back-up name and rename the new file to the original file's name.

**Edit 1**
I just noticed your `javascript` tag. So what type of problem is this, `Java` or `Javascript`?

Comment: I have written in the title..."in java"
I want to do it programatically in java. I dont know if I may need to use javascript

Comment: Just remember to `reaplaceAll()` with 'char()' before 'varchar()'.